# python Combine multiple compile expressions in findall

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I wrote a code myself and it goes like this

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import pandas as pd

URL = 'https://www.books.toscrape/j/detail/164857/963108'
content = requests.get(URL).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")

phone = soup.find_all(text=re.compile("phone|phone"))
name = soup.find_all(text=re.compile("name|name"))
mail = soup.find_all(text=re.compile("mail|mail"))

df = pd.DataFrame([phone,name,mail,])
df.to_csv('D:\\products.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

yes it looks weird, i hope these three fandalls can be merged into one,
like this

```
F = soup.find_all(text=re.compile("phone|phone")),soup.find_all(text=re.compile("name|name")),soup.find_all(text=re.compile("mail|mail"))
```

come and help me

Comment: What problem do you want to solve by merging the "findall"s?

Comment: ，I'm learning it, so I'm curious it should be possible to merge，I wish it looked more concise, and the output value will occupy one line, I want to make the name, phone, and mailbox all on the same line

Comment: what is the correct url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to write it shorter is:

```
data = [soup.find_all(text=re.compile(pat)) for pat in ("phone", "name", "mail")]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: great, you solved my problem,